# Does it matter if I set a weak password for WSL?

Tags: security, virtualization, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have a Windows operating system with Windows Hello PIN setup for login.  I also have installed WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I don't run SSH server under WSL.  However, Windows (so WSL as well) is connected to internet at all times.

So without SSH running in WSL, does it matter if I set a weak login password for my WSL instance? Will it compromise my security in any way?  Also when will the strength of the WSL password matter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

*Short Answer:*  Reasonably low exposure risk, but catastrophic if it happens.  Set a strong password anyway.

*More Detail:*

As long as you are not running any services in your WSL instance that are exposed to the outside world (e.g. `sshd`), then no, there's not much *chance* of someone getting access to your WSL system with a weak password.

In addition, even when you run SSH in WSL2, it's running in a virtual NIC which is NAT'd behind the Windows network.  Unlike WSL1, it's not easy to directly access services in WSL2 from the network.  The Windows host itself gets a little added "magic" from a WSL2 feature known as "localhost forwarding", but that doesn't extend to other machines on the network.

And from the perspective of WSL *itself*, there's really very little "protection" in the user password.  E.g.

```
wsl ~ # Launches your default WSL instance with the default user, but no password
wsl ~ -u root # Launches into the default WSL instance as root, with no password needed
```

And regardless of the permissions of the WSL user (root or otherwise), they are still limited to what your *Windows* user can do.  While WSL `root` doesn't gain Windows "Administrator" privileges, there's still a lot of damage that an attacker could do if they had access to your Windows account.

Regardless, there are multiple reasons for setting a stronger password:

1. *If* someone gains access, the results could still be catastrophic (see next section).
2. There's practically no *disadvantage* to setting a strong password.  You don't have to type it to login.  You type it for `sudo`, but you can disable `sudo` passwords for your user, if you'd like.  Again, it (practically) has the same effect locally as `wsl -u root` anyway.  Still, not necessarily *recommended*, as the `root` user could install malware *within* the WSL instance (see below).
3. As LPChip mentions in the comments, the fallacy in thinking that you are safe because you have all outside services turned off is that you may, in the distant future, turn back on one of those services without reconsidering the consequences.
4. There's even the possibility that you might do things that you *think* are "safe" that will have unintended consequences in exposing outside services.  For instance, WSL doesn't support Systemd, but many people attempt to use Systemd via some "hacks".  There's no judgment in the word "hack" here -- I've done it myself; it's just a great example of something with a *lot* of (both intended and unintended) side-effects.

   For example, one of the default services enabled by Systemd is ssh.  So even though you might not have intentionally exposed ssh (with your weak password) to the outside world, running any one of the Systemd enablement scripts would likely turn it on without you even realizing it.
5. On a similar note, there's always the possibility of future Windows/WSL releases changing how things work.  For instance, WSL doesn't support Systemd today.  But if one day, WSL begins supporting Systemd (in some fashion), then it could have the same effect as the above.  Likewise, as mentioned, WSL2 doesn't make it easy to access services running in it from the network, but Microsoft could always change/improve that in the future as well.

In general, as we all know, *"Security"* is a series of related (but sometimes unknown) services/events/practices/etc..  It's best to be redundant, and even though we *think* the threat is low, implement best practices (such as strong passwords) regardless.

---

##### What would be the consequences of someone logging in to WSL as your user?

In short, without taking extra measures to disable WSL features, it would be catastrophic if someone *did* get remote access to your WSL instance:

- In general, once a theoretical attacker had access to your WSL instance as your user, they would have access to pretty much anything that runs with the permissions of your Windows user.
- They would have *unlimited* permissions within the WSL instance itself, since they could run `wsl.exe -u root` to start a new (nested) WSL instance with full root permissions.
- While that root user wouldn't have Administrator access to Windows, it could install malware/keyloggers/etc into the WSL instance, allowing it to capture passphrases (and more) entered in the instance.
- Both the WSL user and the root user would have access to any documents and data that are accessible to your Windows account on any drive, even (AFAIK) drive-level encrypted data (e.g. Bitlocker), since that's unlocked when you log into *Windows*.
- The WSL user can, of course, run any Windows `.exe` that doesn't require UAC-elevation.  This includes, for instance, `powershell.exe`.
- I'm somewhat confident that the attacker could access e-mail running in an open Outlook under Windows (and even send) -- Not through the Outlook GUI directly, but through scripting/API access to the Outlook instance.  I believe this can be done without additional authentication.
- It's also highly likely that the attacker could script your web browser via Selenium et. al. (i.e. ChromeDriver).  This would include being able to access any information on websites that you are currently logged into via an active session.

Note that much (but not all) of this can, in theory, be mitigated by turning off the automatic mounting (via `/etc/wsl.conf) of Windows drives, as the` wsl.exe`command (that lives on the`C:` drive) would then be inaccessible from within WSL itself.  Also, documents and data on the Windows drives would not be accessible to the WSL user.

In addition, you can use `/etc/wsl.conf` to disable the ability to run Windows `.exe`'s within WSL.

Of course, those features are two of the biggest *advantages* of WSL, so disabling them is a significant blow to functionality.

Comment: Sidenote to the above answer: if at any point in the future you open things up, your weak password will become an issue. Its often an oversight opening services to also check all passwords that can be used. If you are 100000% sure you will never open this to the public in the future, then there is no problem. Otherwise, it is good practice to use a strong password instead, just in case you do open up ports in 5 years from now and not think about changing your password then.